# Fabric text using monogram font doesn't render properly on canvas

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I'm currently working on a project where I use fabric js to create a canvas to show users how their initials would like in a monogram style image. The problem is the canvas does not render the text properly.

The rendered text looks like this:

[pls click this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7B0G.png)

but when I click anywhere in the image will be fixed. It should look like this:

[pls click this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLUcy.png)

I create the canvas like this:

public function print_form_initials($initials) {

```
    if($initials) {
        $left_letter    = strtolower(substr($initials, 0, 1));
        $center_letter  = strtoupper(substr($initials, 1, 1));
        $right_letter   =  $this->substitute_circle_monog_third_char(substr($initials, 2, 1));
        $val = $left_letter . $center_letter . $right_letter;
    } else {
        $val = 'rE4';
    }

    $html =     '<canvas id="canvas" width="130" height="130"></canvas>';
    $html .=    '<script type="text/javascript">';
    $html .=    'jQuery(window).load(function(){';
    $html .=    'var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");';
    $html .=    'var text = new fabric.Text("' . $val . '", {';
    $html .=    'fontFamily     : "circle-monogram",';
    // $html .= 'fontSize    : 100,';
    // $html .= 'selectable     : false,';
    // $html .= 'top        : 3,';
    // $html .= 'left       : 3';
    $html .=    '});';
    $html .=    'canvas.add(text);';
    $html .=    '})';
    $html .=    '</script>';

    // output the html

    return $html;
}
```

I load the font using font-face property. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you are creating the canvas the font is not loaded yet.
Use some font loader with callback or use some delay technique to render the canvas again after 1 or 2 seconds.